# How to identify which workflow rule sent an email?

Tags: workflow, email-alert

Is there any way to quickly identify which Workflow rule caused an email to be sent?
I have tried to use tooling to query the WorkFlowAlert and WorkFlowRule objects. I haven't been very successful, since I couldn't find the exact names for the fields on these objects.

I tried to follow the instructions given in this link.
https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gm9cAAA

I did not get the X-SFDC-EntityId property in the headers.

I also downloaded the outgoing email log from the org, but it doesn't reveal this information.

Is there any other way to get this information? I have also turned on the debug logs with the finest setting for workflows, but it doesn't provide me with this information. **What am I missing?**

Edit: 
This are all of the SFDC fields in the email header properties.

```
X-SFDC-LK: 00D3000******
X-SFDC-User: 005300*****y
X-Sender: postmaster@salesforce.com
X-mail_abuse_inquiries: http://www.salesforce.com/company/abuse.jsp
X-SFDC-TLS-NoRelay: 1
X-SFDC-Binding: 1WrIRBV94myi25uB
X-SFDC-EmailCategory: Not Specified
X-SFDC-Interface: internal
```

Comment: Can you find which email template is that? You can retrieve all of them using metadata api (package.xml), then you find exact template, then you try to delete it to see where is it referenced (in workflow alerts and corresponding forkflows). That should narrow the search

Comment: Out of curiosity: what can you see on the email headers?